# Как изменить язык в Android Stuido?

Tags: android, android-studio

Можно ли изменить язык среды разработки Android Studio? Если да то на какие языки и как?

Comment: В самой IDE, настройки и прочее? нет, доступен, слава богу, только английский язык и надеюсь никому в голову не придет что то там русифицировать

Answer (score 15, accepted):

У врачей общепринятым языком общения является латынь, даже деревенский фельдшер выписывая диагноз не преминет написать DS или щегольнет словечком анамнез. И в этом есть глубокая правда жизни - диагноз выписанный врачом в России поймет доктор даже где-нибудь в Африке - сам лично был свидетелем, когда в богом забытой Камбодже местный коновал спокойно разобрал каракули московского коллеги.

У нас, у прогеров/кодеров/девелоперов таковым является английский язык, это может нравиться или не нравиться, но это факт против которого бесполезно протестовать.

Так что надо знать английский язык, хотя бы в мере достаточной для того, чтобы пользоваться Android Studio.

Если вам, все таки неймется - возьмите файл `resources_en.jar`, который лежит в каталоге `lib` Android Studio, распакуйте его и переведите несколько тысяч ресурсных строчек на русский язык, типа:

```
attempt.to.modify.read.only.document.error.message=Attempt to modify read-only document
typing.in.editor.command.name=Typing
errors.panel.go.to.errors.first.radio=Go to high priority problems only
errors.panel.go.to.next.error.warning.radio=Go to next problem
customize.highlighting.level.menu.item=Customize Highlighting Level
move.caret.command.name=Move caret
guarded.block.modification.attempt.error.message=Unable to perform an action since it changes read-only fragments of the current document
guarded.block.modification.attempt.error.title=Guarded Block Modification Attempt
close.editor.annotations.action.name=Close Annotations
editor.annotations.action.group.name=Annotations
move.cursor.command.name=Move Cursor
paste.command.name=Paste
move.selection.command.name=Move selection
typing.command.name=Typing
hector.import.popup.checkbox=Import &popup
hector.highlighting.level.title=Highlighting Level
hector.none.slider.label=None
hector.syntax.slider.label=Syntax
hector.inspections.slider.label=Inspections
action.duplicate.block=&Duplicate Block
action.duplicate.line=&Duplicate Line
increase.editor.font=Increase Font Size
decrease.editor.font=Decrease Font Size
forced.soft.wrap.message=This document contains very long lines. Soft wraps were forcibly enabled to improve editor performance.
forced.soft.wrap.hide.message=Hide notification
forced.soft.wrap.dont.show.again.message=Don't show again
editor.notification.default.action.name=Notification actions
editor.notification.settings.option.name=Settings...
```

JetBrains в свое время портировали Intellij IDEA (читай ту же Android Studio) на японский, но потом отказались, сказав, что дескать выхлоп был никакой. Это не стоило потраченных на локализацию усилий - японские девелоперы отнюдь не кинулись покупать IDEA :)

Comment: а я попробую перевести, это поможет и мне и другим ... для русского языка полезно включить в свой тезаурс и новые термины , если есть ,и новые понятия ...

Comment: Я распаковал этот jar, а там куча файлов...

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110712/discussion-on-answer-by-barmaley-red-star-----android-stuido).